# Cast to struct in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, casting

I've never seen this kind of cast:

```
(CGRect){.origin = CGPointZero, .size = contentSize}
(CGPoint){0,1}
```

Can someone explain the logic? Is this a C language feature? Or only in Objective-C?
Thanks.

Comment: `{.origin = CGPointZero, .size = contentSize}` is a designated structure initializer - a C99 feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [designated initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) and it's a feature of the C language. The cast in front is a convenient way to initialize structures on a single line or give as an argument to a function, e.g.

Structure initializing:

```
struct a test;
test.member1 = 3;
test.member2 = 5;

// equals 

struct a test = (struct a){ .member1 = 3, .member2 = 5 };
```

Function argument passing:

```
[self function1:test];

// equals

[self function1:(struct a){ .member1 = 3, .member2 = 5 }];
```

Comment: I doubt that's what OP is asking about: designated initializers are allowed only in initialization constructs, and they do not need a cast.

Comment: Depending on the context, this could be a compound literal feature as well ([link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)).

Comment: That is what I was asking about... This is a good thing to know. And to think that for years I've been creating CGPoints with CGPointMake()...